# Data science project example

Tags: jupyter-notebook, data-science

Do anybody know about a github repo with a full well organized data science project? Preferable in Python. My hobby project often get mezzy with a mix of Python code and notesbook. A worked out project is the best way to learn some new tricks.

Answer (score 4):

Data Science is regarded a bit differently by different people, so you might consider focusing on what exactly you wish to learn.

But, take a look at those:

1. https://github.com/bulutyazilim/awesome-datascience
2. https://www.kaggle.com/

The first one contains lots of relevant sources of information. The second is originally a competition site with varied different problems in ML, but also contains past competitions (and datasets). They added a cool feature called "kernels" which are just code files people publish and you could learn from those.